# How to fetch data from firebase for PWA

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a PWA in which i am getting data from firebase. Once the page is loaded ADS( in form of objects ) are retrieved from firebase and then displayed. What i want is that once page is loaded if user has lost the connection or is offline, the cache stores all objects that are once loaded at time user was having connection and made them available for offline use i.e without connection to internet.

[Link to Download JSON FILE of firebase data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lfAqEbOTRU6JcsQI9nj4RtsWdLP4Hxve/view?usp=sharing)

and here is the code i am using in service worker

```
var cacheName = 'test me';
const filesToCache = [
'./',
'home.html',
'details.html',
'/css/main.css',
'/css/home.css',
'/images/nokia.png',
'/js/app.js',
'/js/main.js',
'/js/home.js'
 ];   

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('v1')
        .then(res => {
            console.log('wait.........!')
            return res.addAll(filesToCache);
        })
);
console.log('installed');
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
console.log('activated');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CacheAPI](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/cache-api) for that:

```
const url = '/myAPI/endpoint'
fetch(url).then((res) => {
  return caches.open('v1').then((cache) => {
    return cache.put(url, res)
  })
})
```

To retrive it:

```
caches.open('v1').then((cache) => {
  cache.match('/myAPI/endpoint').then((res) => {
    //res is the Response Object
  })
})
```

You can find a lot more here: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker

Comment: how can i fetch data from firebase and then add that into my cache , i'm a newbie in cache's and fetch. Thanks

Comment: I think Firebase got a pretty decent documentation on that topic: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data and some example: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js

I think what you asking is a bit broader than just how to save data in the cache. Hope it helps anyway!